# Проблема с выборкой данных из бд mysql

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Сразу к делу. Есть задача вывести из бд на странице например: список книг и рядом должен быть автор(имя автора) конкретной книги. Так же вывести автора и рядом должен быть список книг которые он написал. Есть две таблицы в бд:[image: Книги]

[image: Писатели]

Я предполагаю что для этого необходимо связать таблицы (один ко многим). Что я и попытался сделать на примере. Но вот в голову не приходит как правильно составить запрос и отобразить на странице именно так как я описал выше или связать правильно таблицы подскажите пожалуйста. Простой запрос на выборку данных получается сформировать 'SELECT * From books' который выводит все данные из бд а вот как правильно сделать вывод книг и что б соответсвующий автор выводился тут я затупил просто(. Заранее спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Это первое. Второе - сырой SQL-запрос нужен, или всё-же пользуетесь какими-либо современными средствами?

Comment: Ну дословно задача звучит так. Необходимо отображать автора в списке книг рядом с ее названием.  
В списке писателей у каждого из них должен выводиться список написанных  
им книг. По сути да нужен обычный sql запрос который будет выбирать данные по указанным критериям .

Comment: Просто используйте в `SELECT` запросе `LEFT JOIN` для добавления к запросу содержимое из других таблиц по необходимым условиям. Они могут быть явными или взятыми из полей основного запроса.

Comment: Ваш ответ помог решить проблему спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Запрос, который выведет автора рядом с книгой**

`SELECT b.*, w.name FROM books b LEFT JOIN writers w ON w.id = b.writer_id`

Сразу же обращу внимание, что в запросе намеренно указал `writer_id` вместо указанного Вами столбца `id_writer`. Дело в том, что есть некие *паттерны названия столбцов*, таблиц и отношений, которых следует придерживаться для поддерживаемого и масштабируемого проекта. К примеру, названия таблиц пишется множественным числом, столбцы, которые ссылаются на внешние таблицы, называются по паттерну `{foreign table name}_{foreign table column}` и так далее. Советую почитать об этих паттернах побольше, тогда проектировать БД станет легче.

**2. Запрос, который выведет авторов вместе с книгами.**

Дело в том, что из-за реляционности БД, мы не можем получать коллекции, мы можем получать только строки. При таком раскладе, получение всех книг авторов мы должны разбить на два этапа:

1. Получение авторов
2. Получение книг для каждого автора

В данной ситуации на пользу приходит *жадная загрузка*, которая *избавляет нас от антипаттерна N+1*. Во многих фреймворках и ORM это идет из коробки:

```
//пример из ORM Eloquent, входящей в Laravel:
$author = \App\Author::with('books')->get();
```

Данный код в Laravel сделает 2 запроса в БД: 
 1. `SELECT * FROM authors`
 2. `SELECT * FROM books WHERE author_id IN (*ID авторов выше*)` А затем совместит это в единую коллекцию.